# Consulta por pantalla

Tags: android-studio

Hola amigos del foro esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, tengo en un fragment varios elementos como son los edittext, los buttons y un tabledlayout, este es el xml que se posee actualmente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/segundo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
tools:context=".Controlador2.repuestos">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/id"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtitem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/item"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spparte"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sprepuestos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="60"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtrepuestos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/descripcion3"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="5"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtunidad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/unidad1"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txticantidad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/cantidad"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmdingresar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
            android:text="@string/botoningresar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmdmodificar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
            android:text="@string/botonmodificar1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtparte"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/j"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/l"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/m"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtoriginal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtalternativo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtactivo11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tbldatos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tbldatos1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

al correrlo no me muestra todos los elementos solo hasta el botón cmdmodificar, y faltan tres elementos más por hacer que son la búsqueda, una caja de texto y por último un separador, como se puede hacer para ver todo, en si mi consulta es posible trabajar con dos scrollview en un solo fragment, ojala que me puedan asesorar y desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

lo hice de esta manera para que me alcanzara a entrar en el dispositivo, este es el código actual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/segundo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
tools:context=".Controlador2.repuestos">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/id"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtitem"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/item"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spparte"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sprepuestos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="60"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtrepuestos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/descripcion3"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="5"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtunidad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/unidad1"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="57dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="outline"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
            app:endIconMode="clear_text">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/txtcantidad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/cantidad"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmdingresar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
            android:text="@string/botoningresar"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cmdmodificar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boton_redondo"
            android:text="@string/botonmodificar1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/j"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/k"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/l"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtoriginal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtalternativo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtactivo11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbldatos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbldatos1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ojala que alguien les sirva y de modelo, ya que soy nuevo en estas lides y la unica solución que encontre.